# How to use Mechanize to fill HTML forms in Python

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm new to mechanize, and i don't quite understand how does it work, I tried a lot of tutorials, but most of them were outdated and didn't work.

First question is, What effect does Mechanize make? does it fill forms in specific browser so end-users can see it, Or does it make everything in Mechanize browser that cannot be seen by end-user?

I'm trying to make Mechanize fill out the form, Form changes input name after reloading page, How can i change its value by number?

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser() 

br.set_handle_robots(False) 

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 

gitbot = br.open("https://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register") 

br.select_form(nr=0)

br["user[username]"] = "username" 

br["user[email]"] = "email"     

br["user[password]"] = "password"

sign_up = br.submit()
```

Error i am getting after executing code:
`NameError: name 'username' is not defined`

I want to fill out all the forms on the page, without using input name, How can i do it?

Comment: You need to pass  a string as the username i,e `"foobar"`, what do you expect `username`  to be? You need the same for email and password. Also `br["user[login]"]` is wrong

Comment: "name" - the first field on page.

Comment: yes, but you have to pass in the username, I will write an answer in a minute and show you how to do it

Comment: oh i understand now, but now it gives me this error: `mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'user[username]'

Comment: There is also a no captcha recaptcha https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html so I am afraid all bets are off

Comment: reCaptcha is actually easiest one to bypass, On the first click it lets user in, On the second it doesn't, i think i can use cookiejar for that, but thats not thing i wanna do right now, i'm doing this to easily register when needed.

Comment: I don't think you quite grasp what is involved, you answer posts to the search form and has no relevance to registering at all, you need the captcha response and a lot of the elements are not even visible when the page is first loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution:

Forms are actually containing controls, Thats why i needed to select form.

Code that fills out forms on this specific website:

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser() 

response = br.open("https://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register")

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 

gitbot = br.open("https://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register") 

br.select_form(nr=1)

br.set_all_readonly(False)

br.form.set_value("test", nr=0)

br.method = "POST"

response = br.submit()

print response.geturl('http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register/register')
```